# Common heap behavior for Wildfly or application memory leak?

Tags: wildfly, heap-memory, visualvm

We're running our application in Wildfly 14.0.1, with a -Xmx of 4096, running with OpenJDK 11.0.2.  I've been using VisualVM 1.4.2 to monitor our heap since we previously were having OOM exceptions (because our -Xmx was only 512 which was incredibly bad).

While we are well within our memory allocation now, we have no more OOM exceptions happening, and even with a good amount of clients and processing happening we're nowhere near the -Xmx4096 (the servers have 16GB so memory isn't an issue), I'm seeing some strange heap behavior that I can't figure out where it's coming from.

Using VisualVM, Eclipse MemoryAnalyzer, as well as heaphero.io, I get summaries like the following:

**Total Bytes: 460,447,623**

**Total Classes: 35,708**

**Total Instances: 2,660,155**

**Classloaders: 1,087**

**GC Roots: 4,200**

**Number of Objects Pending for Finalization: 0**

However, in watching the Heap Monitor, I see the Used Heap over a 4 minute time period increase by about 450MB before the GC runs and drops back down only to spike again.  Here's an image: [image: image of the memory spikes]

This is when no clients are connected and nothing is actively happening in our application. We do use Apache File IO to monitor remote directories, we have JMS topics, etc. so it's not like the application is completely idle, but there's zero logging and all that.

My largest objects are the well-known io.netty.buffer.PoolChunk, which in the heap dumps are about 60% of my memory usage, the total is still around 460MB so I'm confused why the heap monitor is going from ~425MB to ~900MB repeatedly, and no matter where I take my snapshots, I can't see any large increase of object counts or memory usage.

I'm just seeing a disconnect between the heap monitor, and .hprof analysis.  So there doesn't see a way to tell what's causing the heap to hit that 900MB peak.

My question is if these heap spikes are totally expected when running within Wildfly, or is there something within our application that is spinning up a bunch of objects that then get GC'd?  In doing a Component report, objects in our application's package structure make up an extremely small amount of the dump.  Which doesn't clear us, we easily could be calling things without closing appropriately, etc.

Comment: Well, an application server is always doing something (its subsystems are). This consumes memory. That memory gets released after some time (GC). As per your observation, all that memory does get released. I'm not seeing anything in what you present as out of the ordinary. If you feel there is, you should at least have a clear case of why this behaviour should not occur.

Comment: I definitely didn't have an obvious reason why this might not be expected, other than the fact that we had OOM problems previously (but that was due to the ridiculously low heap size) and over the past couple of years I've been correcting several sub-optimal processing sections of the code.  I've just started to really analyze our heap performance because of our previous issues and so was mainly curious if this is standard behavior.  Figured it probably was since I wasn't seeing any actual problems now, but the jump in memory size just seemed quite a bit over a short amount of time.   Thanks!

Comment: As long as you have the impression that all the short term memory increases get released in full, I wouldn't worry about it that much.